# How to assign quip license type to user (Advanced vs Plus)?

Tags: quip

I am trying to figure out where to set the license type for quip users.  Quip has plus and advanced and I would like some users to have quip advanced version and some just quip plus.

Does anyone know where this gets set?  I've been searching online for this information, but I can't find it.

Comment: Can you check if below article helps you (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000356418&type=1)

Comment: I figured it out, by adding the user to the quip permission set, this effectively gives them quip advanced.